# Ringtone on notification received in Ionic for ios and android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

Is there a way to trigger a ringtone when a FCM notification is received in Ionic. I am using Ionic FCM Library [Link is here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/). In native android it is possible to include code on the FCM `onMessageReceived` method to execute and trigger the ringtone. Similarly is there a way in Ionic to trigger ringtone for both `iOS` and `android`

Is there a way to run `provider` in the background when notification is received (When app is not opened).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [push plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/).

You can specify sound file to be played when notification is received.
sound -> string ->
The name of the sound file to be played upon receipt of the notification.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com) push notification and its free follow their documentation it work perfectly. Push Pluing will be shut down from 31-jan-18. 
OneSignal Postman

```
app_id = "your app_id",
contents = new { en = strMessage },
filters = new filters[]
    {
      new filters { field = "email",key="key",relation="=",value=strEmailID}
                    },
small_icon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PushImage"],
large_icon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PushImage"],
android_sound = "yoursoundfile",
ios_sound = "yoursoundfile.caf",
```

if you are using ionic push
Ionic postman

```
{ 
    "tokens" : ["your Token"],
   "profile" : "prod",
   "notification":{
       "title" :"Test",
       "message" : "Message",
                   "ios": {
                     "priority": 10,
                    "sound":"AmberAlert.caf"
                   }
                 }    
}
```